# INSERT INTO not adding anything to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make INSERT INTO work.

```
if (isset ($_POST['send']) ){
mysql_query('INSERT INTO msg (message, receiver, sender) VALUES ("'.$_POST["message"].', '.$_GET["user"].', '.$sendernick["nick"].'") ');
}
```

I tried to echo every single variable and they appear. 
But this inserting adds nothing to my database.
Did i mess up something here?

To see errors I added this but nothing appear:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors','1');
```

Comment: are you connected to a database? also, your VALUES are basically one long string. you need to examine those quotes

Comment: Two things: 1. Your query may be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. [Read this](http://bobby-tables.com) for information about what they are and how to prevent them. 2. Don't use `mysql_`, use `mysqli_`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the double quotes:

```
mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO msg (message, receiver, sender) VALUES ( "'.$_POST["message"].'", "'.$_GET["user"].'", "'.$sendernick["nick"].'" )' );
```

Also, read about parameter binding and sql injection [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using the `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and will not be supported any more! Please consider using `PDO` instead, as it provides a common way to connect to all types of databases. `Mysqli_*` functions are an option as well, but that will limit you to just using `MySQL`.

Here is an example of how to use `PDO` and get your query working using prepared statements:

```
// connect.php
$db_host = '127.0.0.1'; 
$db_user = 'user';      
$db_pass = 'pass';
$db_name = 'database_name';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_pass);

// the-script-youre-posting-to.php
require('connect.php');

$message = $_POST['message'];
$receiver = $_GET["user"];
$sender = $sendernick["nick"];

// Using prepared statements almost eliminates the possibility of SQL Injection.
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO msg(message, receiver, sender) VALUES (:message, :receiver, :sender)");
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
$stmt->bindParam(':receiver', $receiver);
$stmt->bindParam(':sender', $sender);
$stmt->execute();
```

For more information regarding prepared statements, have a look at the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: looks more difficult but thanks :D